# How to show that $(1+x)^{y} - xy \le 1$

Tags: calculus

How to show that $(1+x)^{y} - xy \le 1$, where $x>0$ and $y$ is a real number in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is a variant of the Bernoulli inequality

Comment: Tried a bunch of stuff: partial derivatives to minimize the function, plug many values looking for a counter-example, countless mathematical manipulations of the inequality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Write out the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^y$.

Here is a reference for the same: https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-binomial-theorem/

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$${\displaystyle (1+x)^{y }=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\binom {y }{n}}x^{n}}=1+xy+\frac{x^2}{2!}(y-1)y+\frac{x^3}{3!}(y-1)(y-2)y+...$$

Answer (score 1):

Here a way using the concavity of the logarithm:

\begin{eqnarray*}y \log(1+x)
& = & (1-y)\log 1 + y\log(1+x) \\
& \stackrel{concavity}{\leq} & \log(1-y+y(1+x)) \\
& = & \log(1+xy)
\end{eqnarray*}